# How to get _id MongoDB/php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I do this way:

```
$cursorLocations = $collection->find( array("locationName" => $locationName) )->limit(1);

if ($cursorLocations->count(true) == 1) {
    $idLocations = $cursorLocations->getNext();
    echo $idLocations["_id"];
}
```

I immediately apologize if this question has been, but read the documentation did not find an answer.

Maybe some other way to get the _id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Mongo :

```
db.collection.find({'field': 'value'}, {'_id' : 1});
```

in PHP:

```
$cursorLocations = $collection->find( array("locationName" => $locationName), array('_id' => 1) )->limit(1);
```

The above code will limit your query to retrieving only the `_id` field and not the other fields, you would still have to extract the value of that field from the result of the `find()` function - from the `$cursor` object, like in:

```
$_id = $cursorLoactions[`_id`];
```

There is also a MongoCursor method `key()` which returns the current `_id`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.key.php

So you could do this:

```
$cursorLocations = $collection->find( array("locationName" => $locationName) )->limit(1);
$_id = $cursorLocations->key();
```

Comment: Thank you for your message.
Did you write. No error, but it displays NULL.

Comment: @ArtPip I see there is a syntax error in the PHP part where there is a missing ")" in the end of the `find(...)` function, I just posted an edit to my answer, so hopefully it will now work for you :)

Comment: @ArtPip ..sorry, but why are you using the `getNext()` function? Are you trying to get the `_id` of the next record or the current record?

Comment: I thus get the current ID.
Probably something with my version of php or settings, so how to get the id with the key () - NULL.

Comment: Also, not worked findOne, in what may be an issue, php or mongoDb?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? If not, can you copy/paste the exact code? Also, check your server's log for error messages - this would give you a clue why Mongo is not working - it's probably because the mongo module is not loaded into Apache (if you're using Apache that is), also check the username/password if your Mongo is secured with "auth". Here are the steps to install Mongo: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php